# Bottleneck of Web Applications

Tags: javascript, django, performance, web-applications

I am developing a web application using django, postgreSQL, html5 and javascript. The application is javacript intensive and is both read/write intensive. What are some common bottlenecks? What are some things to keep in mind when designing a web application that scales well? What are some tips to improve performance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at http://ilian.i-n-i.org/tag/cache/ there are three articles about caching and how it will help your website.

As for the scales well... are you sure that your application needs it?
Do not get me wring, it is awesome to have multiple database servers, CDN, load balancers etc. but do you really need it? If you are starting a new project you should focus on providing a stable features more than optimizing it for a million hits per day cause you are probably not going to make them(at least in the beginning).
Start with caching, it is easy to implement and effective if it is correctly used. When your visitors get so much that you reach the bottle necks think for them then but not earlier.

The above does not mean that you should write the slowest code that is possible. It only means that the need for extreme scalability comes when you have working application and that if you waste 1 year and a ton gold to build it probably you will miss the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Database database database. Make sure you can add more db servers without lots of pain.
Adding app servers is usually fairly straightforward, but DB replication/clustering can get tricky.

Comment: Before you make sure to be able to replicate DB you should first think about the optimization - optimizing queries, adding proper indexes etc. may be a better idea than mindlessly adding more database servers.

Comment: I'd disagree. In the sort of system where you're worried about things like this then you - at the very least - need a 2nd server for failover/redundancy.

Comment: The database is frequently bottleneck but first you will face the problems with the ORM. ORM systems are awesome but they are too abstract and sometime not so optimized for the specific DB vendor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. It depends on how your application is used. You cannot tell until you know how many users will do concurrent requests. Most of the time it will be your database, depending on how many requests per second it can manage.

So if you know your application patterns (read intensive or write intensive) you can design it for easier scaling. Would it be enough to just do replication?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem from day 1 will be the time taken for the client to download the content from your server. CDN's, minification and combining assets should be a primary concern.

(Un)fortunatly, unless you go Google, you won't become big enough to require multiple application, database servers (no offence).

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions:

1) Since you said read write intensive you need to decide how you will be structuring your database to be more read or write friendly. What will be happening most often. If it is reads then indexes are your friend. If it is writes then be careful of going index crazy.

2) On the client side be careful of writing to the live DOM too often. If you need to do do a lot of loads of say table rows, load them into a parent element in memory and then load that parent element into the DOM all at once.